# Is there a way to square an array and divide it by another array in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, statistics, anova

I want to be able to do post anova planned comparisons in Excel. I have a formula that allows several pairwise tests of the results, for example, for samples a-d

[image]

Where the 1s and -1s determine whether that sample is included in the pairwise comparison (sample a and sample b are in this formula)

I need to implement in excel the expression from the denominator that is in parentheses:

[image]

My data is laid out like so:

[image]

And at the moment, I am just summing individual ratios:

[image]

Is there a more elegant solution than this? Something like sumproduct, but that squares the first array and take the inverse of the second before multiplying them together.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really into math perse, but it seems that you could use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C2:C5^2/$B2:$B5)
```

Drag to the right. This yields the same results as what you currently got at least.